VB.NET: Converting Binary WANG annotation data to something usable
I have a file that has binary data stored in it. The file is WANG annotation file used to store annotations for images. See below

I have tried using annotation/image libraries such as ImageGear and LEADTOOLs, but I am unable to successfully read these files. All I want is to know if there are any text annotations and grab the text information. I found online specifications for WANG annotation, here. I am not sure how to take that information and do something with it.
So far I am importing the file into a byte array.
Dim bytes() As Byte
bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("annotation_file.wng")

I am how I would take that byte data and make it something readable. My question is how would I take the byte array and convert to ASCII, a number, or text?
